# "forwards/backwards" vs "forward/backward" vs "rightward" and "leftward"

Tags: word-usage

Is there a difference between

> The car moves forward
>
> The car moves forwards

as well as between

> The car moves backward
>
> The car moves backwards

and can the same pattern be used for other directional terms such as:

> rightward / rightwards
>
> leftward / leftwards

Answer (score 2):

In US English, the forms with & without the final 's' are interchangeable. In British English (and possibly others), officially, those without the 's' (e.g. backward, forward) are adjectives, and those with the 's' are adverbs*. However in practice they are often used interchangeably.

*Adjective: he is backward in his studies; she is a forward young woman. Adverb: he went backwards in his car, I walked forwards to meet the mayor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you mind giving an example on them used as adverbs? Also, does the appended "s" apply in the exact same way for the words `rightwards` and `leftwards`?

Comment: @Steeven - At least in the US, "rightward/s" and "leftward/s" are extremely rare - in fact, I can't remember the last time I encountered them. "To the right" and "to the left" are the normal constructions, although "right-leaning" and "left-leaning" might be found in political discussions.

Comment: You don't see them much in British English either. Mainly back/for/up/down/in/out.